# How can change color of richtextbox text while writing in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

It changes the color of a selected text, but the selected text appears when typing in the object. How can I solve this?

My function:

```
    private void special_words_colors()
            {
                string s_words = @"\b(for|while|if)\b";
                MatchCollection eleman_eslesmeler = Regex.Matches(input:richTextBox1.Text,
pattern: s_words);
    
                foreach(Match m in s_words)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Orange;
                   
                }
                richTextBox1.Focus();
    
            }
```

My textChanged Event :

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            special_words_colors();
}
```

it is working but while is writing seeing like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ6pf.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color specific words in RichtextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980554/color-specific-words-in-richtextbox)

Comment: [How to color different words with different colors in a RichTextBox while a user is writing and raise an event when that colored text is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358496/7444103)

Comment: Instead of `richTextBox1.Focus();`, set the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionColor` properties to their original values. See the linked post for an example.

Comment: Or you may want to use [Monaco editor in WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885536/3110834).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Thank you very much. İt's worked. But sometimes show selected text. I hope i can solve it.